# Column-wise maximum of two arrays and count the number of times one array has the maximum

Tags: python, numpy

I have two np arrays:

```
a1 = np.array([1, -1])
a2 = np.array([3.7416574e-04, -7.7873659e-01])
```

I want to count the number of times a1 holds the max value column wise.
I calculated max value column wise with:

```
np.maximum(a1, a2)
```

I am not sure how to add a counter for that.

Expected output based on the dummy arrays above:

```
a1 holds the max value 1 time
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do this:

`sum(a1>a2)`

You will get the number of columns that a1 is larger than a2. Similarly,

`sum(a2>a1)`

will get the number of columns that a2 is larger than a1. Likewise,

`sum(a1==a2)`

will give you the number of columns a1 is equal to a2

to understand what's happening, execute just the condition alone and see the result:

`a1>a2`

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes so much sense! Not sure why I wasn't able to think about such a straightforward approach

Comment: You're welcome! please select as best answer if you're happy :)